# How to get index for all the duplicates in a dataframe (pandas - python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with multiple columns, and I want to find the duplicates in some of them. My columns go from A to Z. I want to know which lines have the same values in columns A, D, F, K, L, and G.

I tried:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).apply(lambda x: tuple(x.index)).tolist()
```

However, this uses all of the columns.

I also tried

```
print(df[df.duplicated(['A', 'D', 'F', 'K', 'L', 'P'])])
```

This only returns the duplication's index. I want the index of both lines that have the same values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final attempt is close. Instead of grouping by all columns, just use a list of the ones you want to consider:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'B': [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
                   'C': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]})

res = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: (x.index).tolist()).reset_index()

print(res)

#    A  B          0
# 0  1  3  [0, 1, 2]
# 1  2  4     [3, 4]
# 2  2  5        [5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Different layout of `groupby`

```
df.index.to_series().groupby([df['A'],df['B']]).apply(list)
Out[449]: 
A  B
1  3    [0, 1, 2]
2  4       [3, 4]
   5          [5]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have `.groupby` return a  `dict` with keys being the group labels (tuples for multiple columns) and the values being the Index

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).groups

#{(1, 3): Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64'),
# (2, 4): Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64'),
# (2, 5): Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')}
```

Comment: If a dictionary is required, this is the best answer!